# Order by but one value is always last

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by

I was wandering if it was possible to Order By a column but have a value always come last.

For instance, I'm doing a `COUNT` to see how many sales our employees have, differentiated by type of employee.

This is what I'm getting:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| Status    |  Associate |  Internal  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
 Agended    |     5      |    13
 Canceled   |     0      |     1
 Instaled   |     10     |    24
 TOTAL      |     15     |    38
```

And this is my goal:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
| Status    |  Associate |  Internal  |
+-----------+------------+------------+
 Canceled   |     0      |     1
 Agended    |     5      |    13
 Instaled   |     10     |    24
 TOTAL      |     15     |    38
```

My code is

```
SELECT CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IS NULL THEN ISNULL(bo.stateofcontract,'TOTAL') ELSE bo.stateofcontract END "Status"
, COUNT(CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED')AND CM3.func = 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) "Associate"
, COUNT(CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED')AND CM3.func <> 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) "Internal"
FROM BO
JOIN CM3 ON CM3.cm = BO.employee
WHERE (bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED'))
GROUP BY ROLLUP (bo.stateofcontract)
```

Comment: You are trying to use wrong tool for the job - sql is for retrieving data from the database, representation of the data is user interface concern. You will be able to do it easily in any UI framework you are using in your application.

Comment: I'm using SSMS, but the queries will actually be executed through my website so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: what you demonstrated in sample data doesn't pursuit what you explained.

Comment: FYI the correct spellings are "installed" and "cancelled". I'm not sure what word "AGENDED" is meant to be. Perhaps adjourned?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to "order by a column but have a value always come last". What's the column, and what's the last value?

Comment: @pauLo_0liveira . . . What value do you want last?  Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I want `Cancelled` to come last/first, I just don't want it to be in the middle of the other two.

Comment: @Larnu I was trying to say "scheduled" but didn't remeber the word, and since in my mother language it is said "Agendado".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query a bit by removing some conditions from the `CASE` expressions.  There is also a little trick in SQL Server using `CHARINDEX()` which usually works for such ordering:

```
SELECT COALESCE(bo.stateofcontract, 'TOTAL') as status,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CM3.func = 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) Associate,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN AND CM3.func <> 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) as Internal
FROM BO JOIN
     CM3
     ON CM3.cm = BO.employee
WHERE bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED', 'AGENDED', 'CANCELED'))
GROUP BY ROLLUP bo.stateofcontract
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(status, 'Canceled,Agended,Instaled,Total');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ORDER BY a CASE expression, or add an ordering column in the SELECT.  EG:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IS NULL THEN ISNULL(bo.stateofcontract,'TOTAL') ELSE bo.stateofcontract END "Status"
, COUNT(CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED')AND CM3.func = 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) "Associate"
, COUNT(CASE WHEN bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED')AND CM3.func <> 'ASSOCIATE' THEN 1 END) "Internal"
FROM BO
JOIN CM3 ON CM3.cm = BO.employee
WHERE (bo.stateofcontract IN ('INSTALED','AGENDED','CANCELED'))
GROUP BY ROLLUP (bo.stateofcontract)
ORDER BY case when Status = 'Canceled' then 1
              when Status = 'Agended'  then 2
              when Status = 'Instaled' then 3 
              when Status = 'Total'    then 4  
         end
```

Comment: this worked but I had to add `ELSE` in each `CASE` and add `END` for every `CASE` aswell